# UI-Router: Change url without loading state or defer loading the state?

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular-ui's UI-Router in my project and on state change I want to check if the user has access to the page. If not I popup a login modal.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, toState) {
    if (!authentication.authorize(toState.data.access)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login', {}, {notify: false});
    }
});
```

The login state, using a modal from UI-Bootstrap:

```
angular.module('components.security').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        onEnter: function($state, $modal) {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: "/components/security/login.html",
                controller: 'LoginCtrl as controller'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It's working perfectly fine on the first page load: The ui-view isn't rendered, the login modal pops up, and when the user logs in I call `$urlRouter.sync();` and the view is loaded.

However, if you navigate from page to page this is what **should** happen:

- User is on /pageA, clicks a link to /pageB (which he doesn't have access to)
- Url changes to /pageB
- The ui-view is not loaded, instead the login modal pops up
- After login is complete the modal closes, ui-view loads

Instead what happens is this:

- User is on /pageA, clicks a link to /pageB (which he doesn't have access to)
- Url stays at /pageA
- Login modal pops up
- After login is complete the modal closes, but you're still on page A.

So what I'd really like is that the url actually changes to /pageB but the ui-view doesn't load until you call sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered saving toState and angular.copy(toParams) in your authentication $stateChangeStart listener, then triggering $state.go after the user has logged in?

The URL is not set to /pageB when the user transitions there because when you preventDefault, the transition is prevented (and the url is reset to pageA):

```
        if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeStart', to.self, toParams, from.self, fromParams).defaultPrevented) {
          syncUrl();
          return TransitionPrevented;
        }
```

Comment: I had not, but sounds like a simple and perfect solution. Thanks!